# Cannot get $user from route in controller method with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For which possible reason `dd(User::find(123)->id)` returns the expected user id while `dd($user->id)` returns `null` when opening `http://backend.test/my-route/123` ?

`routes/api.php`:

```
Route::get('my-route/{user}', 'My\Path\To\Controllers\MyController@myMethod');
```

`My/Path/To/Controllers/MyController.php`:

```
    public function myMethod(User $user)
    {
        dd(User::find(123)->id);
        dd($user->id);
    }
```

Comment: Can you `dd($user);` on the first line of your function please? You shouldn't need to find the user if you're already passing it in

Comment: @party-ring I get an empty user model with empty array in the `attributes`.

Comment: Does a user with id 123 exist?

Comment: yes, user id 123 exists

Comment: Try adding a regex to your route `Route::get('my-route/{user}', 'MyController@myMethod')->where('id', '[0-9]+');`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your model is not resolved some how. try using Explicit binding

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('user', App\User::class);
}
```

for more informations have a look at the https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#explicit-binding

Comment: I don't think so, because I get an empty model if I just do `dd($user)`.